# VWP: Multiple visits to the U.S. during more than 90 days

Tags: visas, usa, canada, us-visa-waiver-program, b1-b2-visas

I have recently been accepted as an exchange student in Canada and will stay there for a couple of months. My question is regarding potential visits to the U.S.

I qualify for the Visa Waiver Program which allows me to stay in the U.S. for a maximum of 90 days, however, exiting the U.S. to Canada (or Mexico) does not "reset" these 90 days if I recall correctly.

I do not plan on staying in the U.S. for more than 90 days. But suppose that I want to visit the U.S. once at the beginning of my studies in Canada and a second time at the end of my studies (after 90 days have passed), I would seek multiple entry after more than 90 days.

Will I need to apply for a B-2 visa for that purpose or is there a rule that covers this specific case? **If so, is it "written down" somewhere?** I do have a Canadian study permit (i.e. visa).

Comment: I can see the relation to your suggested possible duplicate, however, I wonder if there is any proof for the statement made in the other thread.